# What is the example of MvxNavigationPage<T> usage within XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Google (as of Feb, 2017) returns only 7 results when searching for "MvxNavigationPage", where only one of them is more or less related to this class and provides no any particular knowledge of it.

`MvxNavigationPage<T>` is not presented neither in any (basic) documentation of MvvmCross, nor in any examples (more or less gathered) about this framework.

So, can somebody give me a hint of how to use it in `XAML`?

Comment: This is about 70% rant and 30% question. I'd consider this rather inappropriate.

Comment: Actually I dont think this question is a rant. I have been searching for documentation on how to use the MvxNavigationPage in the current version of mvvmcross for over a week. Still cant find it. I actually think the title itself is a great question @PaulKertscher

Comment: @PaulKertscher I will say though I will go even further and try to contact the developers of mvvmcross to get some closer on this question. I really need to use a custom navigationpage in my app and I want to see the usage of this in the docs .

Comment: @Agat please look out for updates

Comment: @Hue, I don't think the particular question to MvvmCross guys would change the situation in general. It's been years, but they just don't provide any significant changes in the documentation support. Just brief notes about the updates (as of Jan 2020). So, if not MvxNavigationPage, then lots of other stuff will need clarification. And their answer is usually just "try Sandboxing app from github" (dah, I can use github and I always do, but same way Microsoft could have told "just look at Asp.Net Core sources" instead of providing actually structured helpful docs).

Comment: @Hue, in any case, they use corresponding Slack channel kind of actively, so you can go with such questions there.

Comment: @Agat, I am also in the slack channel, no help there either. I even tried contacting martin directly as well

Comment: Anyone looking to use this, so far it's a dead end for this particular scenario. I will go ahead and try to use Prism Library instead for MVVM support in xamarin forms. https://prismlibrary.com/

Comment: @Hue, totally understand you. Been thinking of moving to Prism several times already as they are way better in documentation. So, good luck with that!

Answer (score 1):

MvvmCross fully supports Xamarin.Forms **only since May 2017** (version 5.0).

Also MvvmCross is fully open source so nothing stops you from reading the source code and **knowing exactly** what any class in the framework does.

You can even search whole GitHub for all references to `MvxNavigationPage` if you need to.

Your question is very attacking. Please keep in mind that the people behind MvvmCross do it for free in their **free time** and are bringing great features and regularly updating the framework. They are also very active here one SO with most questions being answered at the same day when they are asked. There is only a few frameworks that are this active, so it deserves recognition rather than any offensive.

To answer your question. You use `MvxNavigationPage` in place of the Xamarin.Forms `NavigationPage` where required. It is derived from `MvxEventSourceNavigationPage` which in turn derives from Xamarin.Forms `NavigationPage`. The advantage of `MvxNavigationPage` is that it fully supports MvvmCross, like including the typed ViewModel and integrating into the MvvmCross lifecycle.

Comment: the suggestion to "go to the sources" is not quite fair proposal. It sounds kind of "Why do you use Stackoverflow at all?" Or "why don't you just write your own code instead?" I would say even more: I do have MvvmCross repo pulled locally on my machine, but this is not about sources. This is about having proper documentation (at least basic).

Comment: The question itself is quite emotional, I am totally agree with that. However, this is because I am following MvvmCross for more than three years and emphasize the framework growth process all that time. Encouraging everyone I am talking with about mobile development to use it, and how it's great! But I am so tired of lack of at least more or less clear docs during all this period of time for most of important parts!

Comment: And what's more important, this is not because of the lack of docs itself, this is because lots of talks been done about "... we are going to work on docs", "... we are so big, so we will do that and that", but times change, and the only thing stays still: lack of docs.
That's not quite fair to say that all the contributors just do that "for free" and "for nothing". Many of them build it for themselves to have quite convenient tools for building their own projects. And telling all the time how great MvvmCross is they mostly silent about bad documentation.

Comment: Ok, @Martin-Zikmund. It's been already almost three years since, as you've mentioned "MvvmCross" fully supports Xamarin.Forms... but NOTHING has changed since your last response in their docs. Not literally "nothing", but almost no significant changes in providing clear details about the framework functionality. So, no sense in "defending" their bad documentation.

Comment: @Agat I share the same sentiments. I am also looking for examples in the documentation

Comment: Yes I still stand behind defending the team and I will. The framework is open-source. People there are doing it essentially for free and no one forces anyone to use the framework. Users of open-source need to realize this. You can post an issue and ask for clarification or improvement of the docs and ideally donate to support.

Comment: @MartinZikmund Yes I agree with you as well to an extent, we can choose to use another framework. Personally I would love to contribute to mvvmcross, specifically the docs. The challenges are: 1) getting in touch with the team maintaining it and 2) getting to learn the framework in the first place ( which is pretty much impossible for me due to the poor docs)

Comment: @MartinZikmund, you are right. None forces us to use the framework. Same way as none can blame us for declaring the facts: MvvmCross documentation (as well as team support) is just horrible. This is not "sentiment". Those are just facts. Pepole get to stackoverflow to get more knowledge about techs, and they have right to know, that the framework is poweful enough, but have just horrible documentation, which may help them to decide what to do and which framework to use.

Comment: Yes, but you have to be mindful about the psychological standpoint of the statement. People are often very offensive towards open-source maintainers, who then burn out and as a result the projects are then abandoned. So saying they provide horrible support (which I definitely disagree with) is just not a good thing. I personally use MvvmCross for multiple projects and I am perfectly happy with it.